# Doubles not recognized when reading a file with the read_csv2 function

Tags: r, readr

I use the package readr. When I read csv files with semi-colon separator:

```
library(readr)
read_csv2("A;B\n1.3;alpha\n2.345;beta", col_types = "dc")
```

here is the answer I get:

```
Warning: 2 parsing failures.
row col               expected actual
  1   A no trailing characters   .3  
  2   A no trailing characters   .345
   A     B
1 NA alpha
2 NA  beta
```

In other words, the numbers 1.3 and 2.345 are not recognized. 
With comma separator everything is fine:

```
read_csv("A,B\n1.3,alpha\n2.345,beta", col_types = "dc")
      A     B
1 1.300 alpha
2 2.345  beta
```

Are you able to reproduce this? Do you know where it comes from? 
Thanks for your help.

Here is my session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readr_0.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.4
```

Comment: From `?read.csv2`: *"uses `;` for separators, instead of `,`. This is common in European countries which use `,` as the decimal separator."* Maybe try `read_delim(..., delim = ";")` directly?

Comment: It does recognize doubles well when decimal mark is `,`

Comment: @HubertL yes indeed. But I thought read_xxx functions in the readr package were able to detect the decimal separator automatically, so I would expect `read_csv2("A;B\n1.3;alpha\n2.345;beta", col_types = "dc")` to work correctly.

Comment: It actually seems to be a bug since it doesn't take into account the locale

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should use `read_delim()` with the option `delim = ";"`:

```
library(readr)
read_delim("A;B\n1.3;alpha\n2.345;beta", col_types = "dc", delim = ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

tyr defining the separators to tell R what to look for:
library(readr)
`read_csv2("A;B\n1.3;alpha\n2.345;beta", col_types = "dc", sep = ";")`

This will tell it to break on ; .

Comment: `sep` is not an argument of `read_csv2` (I am not talking about `read.csv2`)

Comment: totally right, my bad! I should not work so late and read without glasses! My spelling was awful too!